# Why is there persistent network activity to my ISP's DNS while connected to VPN, but no leaks are detected?

Tags: windows-10, networking, security, vpn, dns

When using a commercial VPN, it creates a virtual ethernet adapter with its own DNS servers. If I check for DNS leaks using any of the websites for that purpose, it shows the VPN's DNS only.

But when I view network activity in Resource Monitor, there is an address for my ISP's DNS server with persistent, very low activity (<100bytes/second). The process is svchost: NetworkService with the -p flag, and the service it contains is dnscache / DNS Client. It remains there even if I completely block that IP range in Windows Firewall.

Is this something to be concerned about?

I attempted to resolve it by disabling the DNS Client service, but then the VPN stops working (with a message about being unable to set system DNS, so it definitely depends on this service).